# Get a list of all sites on Tableau Server using Tableau Server Client into a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, tableau-api

I am trying to get all the site names on the Tableau server using Tableau's Tableau Server Client Lib for Python. The query output is a list and each item in it is also a list. Here is my code:

```
all_sites= []
with server.auth.sign_in(tableau_auth):
    all_sites, pagination_item = server.sites.get()
    print(site.id, site.name, site.content_url, site.state)
```

How do I convert this to do a pandas dataframe to have site.id, site.name etcs as columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested the following code successfully.

```
all_sites= []
all_sites, pagination_item = server.sites.get()
data = []
for site in all_sites:
    data.append([site.id, site.name, site.content_url, site.state])
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.columns = ['id', 'name', 'content_url', 'state']
print(df)
```